# syslog full of APCI messages

Tags: centos, acpi

I've got a Centos 7.2 desktop that is spamming the syslog server and also filling it's /var/log partition with constant messages :

kernel: ACPI: _SB_.PWRB: ACPI_NOTIFY_DEVICE_WAKE event

Can I disable ACPI messages / events or do I just need to filter these messages out in the syslog config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, add acpi=off to boot options in grub config. This doesn't resolve the issue itself but does answer the initial question I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can disable the acpid service, though I suspect this is a BIOS setting to do with WOL support - see if that's enabled and if so, and you don't need it, then disable WOL support.

Comment: I've tried disabling acpid but still get the events showing in syslog.

Comment: Any power-related options in BIOS have been disabled and have even tried updating the BIOS in case it was that causing it but no joy. Have added "apci=off" to grub config which has stopped the messages appearing so whilst I've not fixed the problem, I've at least hidden the symptoms. :-/

Comment: I hate not knowing the root of this kind of problem - ah well